# How to Launch Web Site before launching xunit + Selenium Tests ASPNET 5

Tags: selenium, asp.net-core, xunit, xunit.net

This should be easy, and I can't believe it isn't part of the whole unit testing stuff in VS.NET and especially ASPNET 5 but here it goes:

How the heck do I run the web project that I'm testing before the unit tests run for selenium?

I.e. I want to start up the website (which is angular) AND then run my selenium unit test.

I've tried launching iisexpress from the command line but it doesn't like the ASPNET 5 site when pointed to the wwwroot and I can't find any docs on how to get it to like it, and there is no way to get it to just run the project first then execute testing as far as I can tell without changing the startup projects on the solution which isn't what I want.

(I got selenium working otherwise using net451 as the target in the project and that's all good)

Any ideas on how to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

In your project.json file you will have defined (I'm assuming you are using RC1 for asp.net 5)

```
"commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel"
  }
```

From the command line cd to wherever you have your source code with the project.json file

Then run the following from the command line (I've also assumed that you have the dnx command available on your PATH environment variable)

```
dnx web
```

This should launch your application

Comment: Yes, that launches the application, however doesn't have the unit tests launch it. I need to be able to programatically launch iisexpress like in the old days and then run the selenium tests against it.